# What does class? (class with question mark) mean in a C# generic type constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

While I tried to find an answer to another question I noticed that this code compiles in C#:

```
public void Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : class?
{
}
```

I did not manage to find in the documentation what it even means.

Comment: _"I thought it means T is a nullable reference type, but apparently it does not"_ - why is that apparent?

Comment: Because I get a warning when I try to assign a nullable reference type

Comment: That's exactly what it intends to do, does it not? What would you expect to happen otherwise?

Comment: I get this warning: "A null literal introduces a null value when 'T' is a non-nullable reference type." While you say class? means it is derived from nullable?

Comment: @CodeCaster Please check my edited question: I made an example when I get a warning that says T is non-nullable while we clearly have said that it should be nullable

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: I asked moderator intervention to reopen your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It enforces that T has to be a nullable reference type.

The type you set in for T, must derive from `object?`.

It's a new feature in C#8, to explictly declare a type as nullable.
if you have

```
 Add<T>(T tmp);
```

You document, it's OK to Add null;

Comment: Check my updated question, I have edited it to show the compiler seems to not know this fully. Yet it seems that when I do call Foo it indeed gives a warning if nullability does not match as you say

Comment: I guess I'll need a separate question for that

Comment: If you only would have T : class, and you try to return "null" than this would be an error. It ensures (documents) a variable of type <class> without a ? is holding really something, not null. There is a compiler switch that rules if this produces a warning or an error, cause it's a breaking change, and all the old cold would not work anymore, if it would be declared an error immediatly. So be aware of: Other rules apply, if you look on older code versions.

Comment: My question was really why does it give a warning with T: class? even though we said it's nullable

Comment: `Any nullable reference type (noted by ? after the type in the variable declaration) may be null. Static analysis determines if the value is known to be non-null when it is dereferenced. If not, the compiler warns you.` From here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references. What you should do with the warning- I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems the answer is not quite correct, it's not like it "must" be null, but rather "may be null" which is quite a difference that you probably want to fix. It got me really confused about some other aspects

Comment: P.S. The warning is actually correct, you can check in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631460/c-sharp-8-gives-a-warning-when-returning-a-nullable-generic-with-nullable-constr?noredirect=1#59631499. And thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Great, and sorry to consider this expert question a beginners quetion, I will vote up the question.

Answer (score 1):

To allow your class return `null` value without `CS864` warning you can rewrite your code a little bit

```cs
public T? Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : class
{
    return null;
}
```

The question about `class?` is open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2840) right now. `class?` constraint isn't implemented yet and therefore compiler threats it like regular `class` and generate `A null literal introduces a null value when 'T' is a non-nullable reference type` for now.

You can also refer to the *The issue with T?* section in this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) to see some details. The code sample above is recommended way to deal with nullable generic type

Comment: Yes, I have figured that out in another question already. Yet I cannot understand why  saying class? is not enough for compiler

Comment: Right, so it is a bug, and I was really wondering why it works this strange way :)

Comment: This is not enough for now, there is an open issues for fix that, as you can see in attached GitHub links

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I'd like to say, that it isn't implemented yet. Because [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#nullable-class-constraint) says that it's possible