# C# 8 gives a warning when returning a nullable generic with nullable constraint

Tags: c#, generics, nullable-reference-types

This code:

```
public T Foo<T>()
    where T : class?
{
    return null;
}
```

Gives a following error:

> A null literal introduces a null value when 'T' is a non-nullable
>   reference type

I don't see why we can't return null when we say that T can be nullable. If we additionally try to return `T?` we will get an error that `T` has to be non-nullable.

It seems it's kind of impossible to have a nullable constraint and return a nullable result at the same time.

Comment: How often do you want to post the exact same question? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631254/inconsistent-behavior-in-c-sharp-8-nullable-reference-type-handling-with-generic and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630532/what-does-class-class-with-question-mark-mean-in-a-c-sharp-generic-type-const

Comment: It is not exact the same question even though it might seem like this

Comment: Well, I've already answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631044/4728685) There is a known [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2840) with this constraint

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, in a way. There is not really an answer in these quesitons on github. And I'd like to know how it is possible to return nullable with nullable constraint, which seem impossible

Comment: Obviously as of the current implementation it simply is not possible because of the mentioned bug. Of course there´s no answer on github, because that bug isn´t solved. So what do you expect here?

Comment: I have not seen anyone acknowledged this is a bug and that it will be fixed, or there is some explanation to it

Comment: And it actually does not seem to be the case, don't really understand the attitude. An ordinary valid question, and @canton7 gave an answer that makes sense which means it does not seem this is a bug. So what I expect is a nice answer like the one given, and not strange comments really

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I've added a possible solution for that in linked answer. As other comments say, I'll get an answer when it'll be fixed

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It seems as per the given answer that it actually makes sense that it is not allowed to it this way. So it does not really seem like a bug since constraint means "class can be null". Then everything makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you call:

```
string result = Foo<string>();
```

`result` now contains `null`. But it's a `string`, which is not nullable.

The compiler is warning you that `Foo<T>` may be called where `T` is not nullable, and returning `null` in this case would be unexpected.

Note that `where T : class?` means that `T` *may* be nullable, but it also might not be. Both `string` and `string?` are allowed. I don't believe there's any way to say "`T` **must** be nullable".

---

If you're trying to say:

1. `T` is allowed to be nullable
2. When `T` is non-nullable, then this type can still return `null`

Then you can write:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public T Foo<T>()
    where T : class?
{
    return null!;
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgbgpgTglgZgTwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMA6AERgEMBzAOwHsBnYGAYydIGEGATCAIJ0qAGwRMYTANy4AxHQCuIkVQBGIiIQjD1EXCgDMxNIS6EA3rkLXiRgCoB+QgDEGDADx2AfAAoAlFY2QQDuABbQmnaEIMaB1pY4QUEoAOyEisoyiTYAvnGE+YbEACyEALL++QlJNiREUBBMSsCEALwubu51vn5ZQXk4OUA===)

Note that `MaybeNull` only applies to the method's contract and not its body, when is why we need to return `null!`. However you can see in the SharpLab link above that the caller `string result = Foo<string>();` gets the correct warning.

Comment: well, should not we get a warning since we said `class?` and `string` is not `string?`

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik No. `where T : class?` means "`T` must be a class, and *may* be nullable". It means `T` can be e.g. both `string` and `string?`. If you say `where T : class`, then `T` cannot be `string?`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it now. 'class?' means it can be nullable, but not necessarily nullalbe

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from basic. Let say you have a reference type variable that allows it to have null value. But your program design requires it to be not null all times, if a null value is encountered, it is mostly likely to get the `NullReferenceException`.

To avoid such design issues, The `NullableReference` types was introduced. Means if a reference type is allowed to have null you should mark it as `Nullable` and any usage should check for null value before using it. If checking is not found then compiler will generate a warning.

If you read [this introductory article on NullableReferenceTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types) You will get the fair idea of what is the intent of this new feature.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The whole confusion I got was because I thought that `class?` means it must be nullable. So when it's clear it means can be nullable, all this makes sense